# FUSE issue running in threaded mode

Tags: c, linux, fuse

I've written a filesystem with `FUSE` and everything works as expected in single threaded mode (`-s` flag).

In regular threaded mode, if I issue an `open()` then `read()`, the operation works, but the filesystem seems to hang.  I run it in the foreground and `ctrl-c` doesn't do anything.  However, if I run any stable operations like `ls`, I can shut down `FUSE` with `ctrl-c` just fine.

Is there any way to debug this issue or might anybody know of where to start looking for the bug?

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try! http://old.nabble.com/Debugging-FUSE-Filesystems-td22730976.html